# Why does my template declaration & implementation work inside my pimpl source file?

Tags: c++, templates

so I made a specialized template struct to get two different return types: just `T` and a `vector<T>`. This is declared and defined inside the impl portion of a pimpl-structured class. So the template is a class created inside a class in a source file. For some reason, the compiler thinks this is ok and runtime behavior is as expected.

```
some_class.h

class SomeClass {

  template<typename T>
  T get();

private:
  struct SomeClassImpl;
  SomeClassImpl *impl;
}

some_class_impl.cpp

struct SomeClass::SomeClassImpl {
  SomeClassImpl() = default;
  
  // template class
  template<typename T>
  struct Getter {
    T get() { 
      return T();
    }
  }

  template<typename T>
  struct Getter<std::vector<T>> {
    T get() { 
      return std::vector<T>();
    }
  }

  // makes an instance of the template class to return either vector<T> or T
  template<typename T>
  T get() {
    return Getter<T>.get();
  }

}

// wrapper definition
template<typename T>
T SomeClass::get() {
  return impl->get<t>();
}
```

If I were to to split the template declaration into the `.h` file and implementation in the `.cpp` file, then I would have to do an explicit instantiation inside the `.cpp` file of the template with the types I intend to use such as : `template class Getter<int>`.

So my questions are: why does declaration & implementation of templated class and methods work inside my impl class, and is there a better way to do template specialization inside a pimpl class or should I just ditch pimpl architecture?

Edit:

Here is an example of usage, and also added in more details. Thanks for the reminder

```
SomeClass c;
std::vector<int> v = c.get<int>();
int i = c.get<int>();
```

Comment: Why do you think there should be a problem?

Comment: Since you haven't shown how and where you use/instatiate the templates it's not really clear what you're asking. What exactly is is that you think should not work?

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. We have no idea what precisely you're expecting us to pretend.

Comment: @molbdnilo Perhaps I worded my questions poorly, the main point is: why does template declaration and implementation work inside a cpp file? I haven't seen any applications of someone doing so purely inside a .cpp file.

Comment: @super I thought that all template code must be known to the compiler (via .h file) so it knew what definition to assign it to. If my knowledge is correct, doesn't defining and declaring the templates in the source file mangle its job?

Comment: Yes, that's true, the template definitions must be visible where you use them. But if your program works, you must be making those definitions visible where needed. It's hard to tell without seeing the usage of your code, and your build process.

Comment: @cigien thanks for the clarification, you have a good point that I might be making the definitions visible somewhere. I think that might answer my question, and I can delve deeper

Comment: If a template is defined in a `.cpp` file and also used in the same `.cpp` file there i no issue. As pointed out by cigien, the definition needs to be visible from where it's used. If it's not, then the instatiation needs to come from somewhere else. Explicit intatiation or implicit instatiation from another place in your code where the definition is visible. Either way, your question is still unclear.

Comment: @seanngpack The naming and structuring of files is purely convention and nothing that the language cares about. The important concept is the translation unit (or compilation unit).